# Find most similar documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp, sentence-similarity

How do I find the top 100 most similar documents between two indices in Elasticsearch?

Document #1 is in index1, type11, field111. 
Document #2 is in index2, type21, field211

Edit: Both fields are strings.

I looked at the documentation for [More Like This query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html). But it doesn't tell me how I can quickly compare the results for different kinds of similarity metrics and look at the top results.

Comment: What are the types of field111 and field211?

Comment: Oh.. both are strings.

Comment: Could you provide the ids for both documents you're referring to?

Comment: The initial intent was to find the IDs of most similar document pairs. Is that not possible in Elasticsearch? I know that looping through the document pairs is still possible ... but not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, but substitute the id values for your documents:

```
GET index1,index2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "more_like_this": {
      "fields": [
        "field111",
        "field211"
      ],
      "like": [
        {
          "_index": "index1",
          "_id": "DOC_1_ID"
        },
        {
          "_index": "index2",
          "_id": "DOC_2_ID"
        }
      ],
      "min_term_freq": 1,
      "max_query_terms": 12
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you use multiple similarity measures? Is this the default tf-idf metric?

Comment: today on elastic blog: https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch